# Way to remove keys that have array of zeros as value

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have nested dict as follows:

```
 u'dvlRaw':{
   u'diagnosticInfoUDP': { 
      u'clientConnected': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0,0], dtype=uint8),
      u'channel': array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint32)
     }
 }
```

How to remove the key, value pairs for which values that have entire array of zeros in it.
The position of array of zeros may not be constant, sometimes it may be the value for child_dictionary, sometimes it may be value of child of child_dictionary.
Is there a generic way of removing the occurrence of array of zeros in whichever child_dictionary it may be in

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**? You are commenting on answers now that your question is broader than you've described. Please [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53608633/edit) accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.any` to check if each array contains any non-zero value or not:

```
import numpy as np

diagnosticInfoUDP = dictionary['dvlRaw']['diagnosticInfoUDP']
for key in list(diagnosticInfoUDP):
    if not np.any(diagnosticInfoUDP[key]):
        del diagnosticInfoUDP[key]
```

**EDIT:** A general solution to remove zero-only arrays from an arbitrarily nested dictionary:

```
def clean_dict(dictionary):
    for key, value in list(dictionary.items()):
        if isinstance(value, np.ndarray) and not np.any(value):
            del dictionary[key]
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            clean_dict(value)
```

Comment: This helped me lot. Thanks. But in this case the key names inside nested dict is known, what if I have knowledge only of parent dict i.e only the dictionary name and I have to remove the values of array of zeros inside the dict. Note: the Zero array may be present at any child dict.

Comment: Can we at least assume that all the arrays are nested at the same depth (i.e. 3) or not even that?

Comment: In my case the depth doesn't remain constant. Sometimes it is 2, sometimes it is 3 or 4

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic way:

```
d = {'dvlRaw':{'diagnosticInfoUDP': {'clientConnected': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'channel': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}}}


def all_zeroes(arr):
  return 0 in set(arr) and len(set(arr)) == 1

remove = []
for k, v in d['dvlRaw']['diagnosticInfoUDP'].items():
  if all_zeroes(v): remove.append(k) 

for k in remove:
  del d['dvlRaw']['diagnosticInfoUDP'][k]

print(d)
#=> {'dvlRaw': {'diagnosticInfoUDP': {'channel': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the precise structure you have defined, you can use a dictionary comprehension with [`np.ndarray.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html):

```
import numpy as np

dct = {u'dvlRaw': {u'diagnosticInfoUDP': 
       {u'clientConnected': np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0,0], dtype='uint8'),
        u'channel': np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype='uint32')}}}

res = {u'dvlRaw': {u'diagnosticInfoUDP':
       {k: v for k, v in dct[u'dvlRaw'][u'diagnosticInfoUDP'].items() if v.any()}}}

print(res)

{'dvlRaw': {'diagnosticInfoUDP': {'channel': array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint32)}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new nested dict from your existing dict:

```
bob = {"bob" : {"nob": np.zeros(10), "dob" : np.ones(10)}}

bob2 = {k : {k2 : bob[k][k2] for k2 in bob[k].keys() if not (bob[k][k2] == 0).all()} for k in bob.keys()}
```

In this example my nested dict is named `bob`, i am building a new nested dict from it, in the following way:

- For each key `k` in `bob`, build new dict.
- The new dict will only include keys `k2` from `bob[k]` if `bob[k][k2]` is not all zeros.

Note that i am iterating on keys from bob, `k` , and from each inner dict, on its keys, 'k2', i am using the keys to extract the values.